# display NSMenuItems list

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I created a simple mac OS application and placed NSMenu in the nib file then I create two other files MenuManager.h and MenuManager.m where I created NSMenuIBOutlet and menu items etc. In MenuManager I have a method called setup which creates NSStatusItem and set menu to NSMenu which have created in header file as @property (weak) IBOutputlet NSMenu *menu;

In AppDelegate nib file I have selected Menu and refererenced outlet to menu object in MenuManager.

In AppDelegate I am calling method setup on MenuManager object which creates status item in status bar with image etc but when I click on it then list doens't appear.

Any idea where I am wrong?

Comment: There are several things that could be going wrong, and unfortunately I don't think the question is very clear right now.  Since this issue involves a nib (multiple nib?) files it will be impractical for you to post all the relevant code in the question.  If you make the project available online and link to it then we might be able to help.

Comment: Is your `setup()` being called? can you put a breakpoint or an NSLog inside your `setup()` routine to see if it is being called?

Comment: @AaronGolden thanks for reply. I am trying to write another small sample program to explain the problem. Basically I have one nib file where I have all windows and menus etc and different header and implementation files where I have created IBoutlets and linked them with main nib file. When I call setup method from AppDeletgate then it creates the status item and I can see in the status bar but it doesn't show the whole list. If I place the menu IBOutlet in AppDelegate header and relink the nib then it works fine.

Comment: Please add the code to your question, that shows, how you create the Menu and its items.